# Instance members of my class return null after getting data from UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a class with two NSString data members

Header file

```
@interface WebSiteFavorites : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *titleName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;`

- (id) initWithTitleName: (NSString *)titleName url: (NSString *)url;

@end
```

I have a TVC that uses this class as its data source, and I have hard coded some instances of my class in the appDelegate to populate the TV which works. From the TV i have a add button with a modal transition to a VC. In this view controller I have two text fields where the user enters a name and a url and then I using protocols and delegate to update the TVC (which i don't quite understand). My problem is that after the entering the required info in the text fields my class instance is null.

Here is my code for this

Header 
    @interface WebSiteFavoritesAddFavoritesViewController : UIViewController

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebSiteFavorites *favorites;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *urlTextField;

@property (strong) id<WebSiteFavoritesDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)titleTextFieldChanged;
- (IBAction)urlTextFieldChanged;

- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation

```
@implementation WebSiteFavoritesAddFavoritesViewController

@synthesize favorites = _favorites;
@synthesize urlTextField = _urlTextField;
@synthesize titleTextField = _titleTextField;


- (IBAction)titleTextFieldChanged
{
    self.favorites.titleName = self.titleTextField.text;

}

- (IBAction)urlTextFieldChanged
{
   self.favorites.url = self.urlTextField.text;

}

- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender
{  
    [self.delegate newFavoriteAdded:self.favorites];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

After the IBAction methods i have used break points and favorites is null.
Also I have some questions about protocols and delegates just for understanding.  I have created a separate header file for my protocol, my TVC conforms to the protocol, in my VC i have created the delegate which you can see in my posted code. In my TVC i have implemented the function from my protocol. Is this the proper sequence?

Comment: Where did you instantiate *Favorites* ?

Comment: do you correctly set the 'Favorites' delegate?

Comment: In VC all I have done is declare a property of favorites and synthesize it.  I do not know if I have correctly set the favorites delegate. I find them a little confusing at the moment

Comment: @ legolas I believe that is my problem with it being null.  I'm not passing anything to my VC so it never gets instantiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate `favorites`. Without instantiating objects don't hold the values you assign to them.

So you must do...

```
favorites=[[WebSiteFavorites alloc] init];
```

or as you have another method `initWithTitleName:url:`, do use that to instantiate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes Thank you. What about delegates and protocols? I am having a hard time understanding them. I have my TVC that has a button that uses modal to go to my VC where I can enter information that will be used to update the data source of the TVC. What i have done is created a single header file as my protocol. Then made my TVC adopt that protocol. In the same TVC i have the implementation of the protocol. In my VC, that is used to add a new object, i have created the delegate property and then when the user pushes done button I have this `    [self.delegate newFavoriteAdded:self.favorites];
`

Comment: Here's a nice and brief explanation of creating and using delegates... http://alexefish.com/post/15966868557/understanding-and-creating-delegates-in-objective-c